# JavaFX 8: Is there a way to cast boolean to ObservableBooleanValue or to a BooleanBinding?

Tags: javafx-8

I'm trying to bind the disabled property of a button into 2 observables:
1. If there are no data selected on a specific table
2. If there are more than 1 data selected on the same table.

Doing something like:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.and(Bindings.isEmpty(myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()),
    myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() > 1));
```

'Bindings.and' is not allowing me to do this and is giving the following error:
"*The method and(ObservableBooleanValue, ObservableBooleanValue) in the type Bindings is not applicable for the arguments (BooleanBinding, boolean)*"

I do know that it allows 2 BooleanBindings hence I'm trying to cast the 2nd condition like

```
(BooleanBinding) myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() > 1
```

or

```
(ObservableBooleanValue) myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() > 1
```

and both are restricted as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can't do something like this is that a `boolean` is a primitive value - you can't just cast it to an observable, as it will have no means of knowing when the underlying value changed.

You need to create a binding that will update whenever the underlying values change. Luckily, the [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) class has convenience methods to help with it. In your case, you will need to convert the `ObservableList` into an observable Integer then check whether it is greater than 1:

```
Bindings.size(myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()).greaterThan(1)
```

This will give you a `BooleanBinding` whose value reflects whether there is more than 1 item selected.

As a side note - if the selection is empty it means there are exactly zero items selected, so I think you may have meant `or` and not `and`, as your conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was playing with it and managed to solve it with:     suiteSelectedMoveDown.disableProperty()  .bind(Bindings.notEqual(Bindings.size(suiteCasesSelected.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()), 1)); but yours is much simpler. Missing closing ')' there though. Also, sadly I still can't vote because of lacking reps. :( Thank you though! :)